# Cannot find ResourceDictionary when editing copy of template

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

please forgive me in advance.  First question.

I am working on a WPF project where I have defined a simple resource dictionary at the application level.

```
<Application x:Class="Game.UI.Modals.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="GameResources.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>        
</Application.Resources>
```

The reference to the ResourceDictionary is working fine; I am able to utilize it in XAML with no issues.

The problem I am having is in trying to add templates to the dictionary using the Create ControlTemplate Resource tool (right click => edit template => create empty).  The Resource dictionary radio button in the define in panel is grayed out.

I have tried creating dictionaries in different namespaces, I made sure the dictionary is named and that the build action is set to resource.

Any idea how to get the Create ControlTemplate Resource dialog to recognize my application level ResourceDictionary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include your GameResources.xaml like this instead:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="GameResources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

The create template dialog lists the merged dictionaries. When you include your resources as in my example, the radiobutton should become enabled and your merged dictionary should appear in the list.